# custom policy customization button with css

Tags: css, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I transformed the button to send another code to a link with css. how I can put the link at the beginning of the next line with css like pictures below :

From [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpMO5.png) to [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAdqi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [customize the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

[image]

Something like you would want would just be HTMl moving the div to a different location:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<h2>This is a heading in a div element</h2>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
```